# Is there any problems in Image.open(os.path.join(origin_path,name)).convert('P')?

Tags: computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I changed some images in pascal dataset by opencv,then i need to convert them to P mode.
I used `img = Image.open(os.path.join(origin_path,name)).convert('P')` to convert RGB images to P mode.But the new image is a little strange.Why the color of new image is not smooth as the original?
Is it harmful to my training?How can i deal with it?

Original Image

[image]

New Image

[image]

Comment: Your original image is already a palette image.

Comment: Yes,the problem is from that I used cv2 to change the pixel of it and then used imwrite to save image.But it's RGB and couldn't work in training process.So I need to convert the RGB to palette.I didn't find the opencv method to do it.So I used img = Image.open(os.path.join(origin_path,name)).convert('P').But it works not well

Comment: I don't understand. Your original image is already a palette image - you don't need to open it with OpenCV or PIL to convert it to a palette image because it is already a palette image.

Comment: Because I need to change some pixel of the original image to change some color part to another color. Like change [0,128,0] to [0, 0, 0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I see. You want to modify the palette. You can do that like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Load the source image
im  = Image.open('original.png') 

# Extract the palette into a Numpy array and reshape as 256 RGB triplets
palette = np.array(im.getpalette())
colorVectors = np.reshape(palette,(-1,3))

# Replace any palette entries consisting of [192,128,128] with yellow [255,255,0]
colorVectors[np.all(colorVectors==[192,128,128],axis=-1)] = [255,255,0]

# Put modified palette into image and save
im.putpalette(colorVectors.ravel().tolist())     
im.save('result.png')
```

**Original Image**

[image]

**Output Image**

[image]

---

If you know you want to change a specific palette entry and you know that it is, say, entry `0`, you can do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Load the source image
im  = Image.open('original.png') 

# Extract the palette into a Numpy array and reshape as 256 RGB triplets
palette = np.array(im.getpalette())
colorVectors = np.reshape(palette,(-1,3))

# Make palette entry 0 into magenta
colorVectors[0]=[255,0,255]

im.putpalette(colorVectors.ravel().tolist())
im.save('result.png')
```

[image]

---

**Keywords**: Python, PIL, Pillow, palette, palletised, PNG, modify palette, change palette, alter palette, replace palette, image, image processing.